# HttpURLConnection not fetching data and displaying the result in ListView

Tags: android, httpurlconnection

I have this code that I am trying to run after making all kinds of changes to it. The problem is that i have added permissions and added still find that the code seems to be not working.
It would be a great help if anyone can help me find my mistake. 
Where am I going wrong.
This is the **.java** file.

```
    package com.example.adityapc.phpfeeddisplay;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.AsyncTask;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.ListView;
    import org.json.JSONArray;
    import org.json.JSONException;
    import org.json.JSONObject;
    import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStream;
    import java.io.InputStreamReader;
    import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
    import java.net.URL;

            public class ActivityMain extends Activity {

                private static final String TAG = "Http Connection";

                private ListView listAct = null;

                private ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    listAct = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listActivity);
    final String url = "http://anonymoous.marshalcadetacademy.com/notification.php";
    new AsyncHttpTask().execute(url);
}

public class AsyncHttpTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Integer> {

    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(String... params) {
        InputStream inputStream = null;
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        Integer result = 0;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(params[0]);
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            int statusCode = urlConnection.getResponseCode();
            if (statusCode ==  200) {
                inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
                String response = convertInputStreamToString(inputStream);
                parseResult(response);
                result = 1;
            }else{
                result = 0;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d(TAG, e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
        return result;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {
        if(result == 1){
            arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(ActivityMain.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,R.id.listActivity);
            listAct.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
        }
        else{
            Log.e(TAG, "Failed to fetch data!");
        }
    }
}

private String convertInputStreamToString(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
    String line = "";
    String result = "";
    while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
        result += line;
    }

    if(null!=inputStream){
        inputStream.close();
    }
    return result;
}
private void parseResult(String result) {
    try{
        JSONObject response = new JSONObject(result);
        JSONArray posts = response.optJSONArray("posts");
        String[] blogTitles = new String[posts.length()];
        for(int i=0; i< posts.length();i++ ){
            JSONObject post = posts.optJSONObject(i);
            String title = post.optString("title");
            blogTitles[i] = title;
        }
            }catch (JSONException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

And here is the **.xml** code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/linear" >

        <ListView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/listActivity"
            android:layout_gravity="center">


        </ListView>
    </LinearLayout>
```

If you all have any suggestions to make, your help will be appreciated.

Comment: you need to use handler to update the listview

Comment: Is the data not fetched or is the data not displayed? Please tell what happens.

Comment: where you are passing the values to arrayadapter?

Comment: What is the status code? What do you get in 'String response' ? You are not telling what happens.

Comment: 'blogTitles[i] = title;'. Place a Log.d statement there for title so you know what comes in. Please report.

Comment: Even worse. You are doing nothing with 'String[] blogTitles'. Where you would have to use them for the array adapter as Yashini already told you.

Comment: i am using the 'url' variable for passing the link to the arrayadapter.

Comment: what it should do is fetch the data from the database from the php feed link that is put in the **url** variable and it should display in the **ListView**

Comment: what **String response** is for, that, it should receives the input from the database from **InputStream** in **response** and the **parseResult** gets it as input for **JSONObject**

Comment: Now there is another problem that the **result** comes out to be blank from the **convertInputStreamToString** what goes wrong there?